# Creating a lexer in Clojure

Tags: clojure, token, tokenize, clojurescript, lexer

If I want to pass a string in a function and return the token type of the string typed using Clojure, such as "int x=5;" will be ":alpha :alpha :alpha :whitespace :equal :digit". How will I write the lexer function in Clojure?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [the instaparse library](https://github.com/Engelberg/instaparse). An example:

```
(def as-and-bs
  (insta/parser
    "S = AB*
     AB = A B
     A = 'a'+
     B = 'b'+"))

=> (as-and-bs "aaaaabbbaaaabb")
[:S
 [:AB [:A "a" "a" "a" "a" "a"] [:B "b" "b" "b"]]
 [:AB [:A "a" "a" "a" "a"] [:B "b" "b"]]]
```